# What does the question mark in a file icon mean in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, icons

[image]

I didn't find anything in the official documentation.

I am asking this because these two files have the .pdf extension, maybe the IDE can't recognize them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This icon denotes the "Unknown" to IDE [file type](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/file-types-recognized-by-intellij-idea.html). To be able to open such file from IDE by the external application, please add the extension pattern here:
[image: File Types]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've followed your instructions but in Files Opened in Associated Applications *.pdf is already registered :/

Comment: Where do you see these icons? What happens when you click on them? Have you tried to restart IDE?

Comment: They are in a project directory from where should be downloaded inside the app. When I click them Edge openings to show them. Yes, I've restarted the IDE

Comment: Ok, looks like the icons are not changed on a native ones if IDE Appearance theme is not native (Windows). Related issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-78881

Comment: Oh, ok, good to know. My fear was that the IDE couldn't find the files, so they would affect negatively my app. Thank you for your time

Comment: If this is happening to a known file type, like .log and intellij won't open it. Just assign that file extension to custom file type, that will let you open the file in intellij.

Comment: Thanks, mate, all I needed was to get to the File Types window.